# SimpleModal w/ Date Picker in a "Wizard" Scenario

Tags: datepicker, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal (GREAT library Eric Martin) to create a "wizard" for users to enter data.

I'm making the wizard work by replacing the contents of the Modal's div...

ie:

When the modal is displayed I move the contents of page1 into modalDiv.
When the user clicks next, I move the contents of modalDiv back into Page1 and move the contents of page2 into modalDiv.

This works great, however the problem I have having is that I'm using a DatePicker on page2. From reading the SimpleModal documentation I am initializing the datePicker in the "OnShow" callback... this works great if the DatePicker is on Page1, however this does NOT work if the DatePicker is on page 2.

How do I re-initialize the DatePicker when I load page 2?

Answer (score 1):

Well crap.. right when I finished typing that up I had an idea for a solution, and it worked (and it's probably better).

I put Page1 Div and Page2 Div IN my Modal Div and then hide/show Page1 Div and Page2 Div instead of moving their contents around...

KISS principle... gotta love it...